# Tack a HTML element at the bottom of an existing email body

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my use case:

I have integrated my application with SendGrid, and they provide the user a way to customize the unsubscribe link by adding an element with an `[UNSUBSCRIBE]` in the HTML. Now, there are two reasons why I do not want to edit my existing email templates (HTML files).

1. There are a lot of them.
2. I only want to do this in special cases

So, my thought is that I can tack the HTML onto the end of the existing email body in `PHP` when I go to send out the email, something like:

```
$html = $html . "<div style='position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:100%;'>"
           .        "<div style='margin:0px auto;'>"
           .            "If you would like to stop receiving these emails <a href='[UNSUBSCRIBE]'>click here</a>"
           .        "</div>"
           .     "</div>";
```

But unfortunately, this only places my link at the bottom of the *viewable* email, not the entire email. So when the user scrolls down, the link is stuck in the middle of the email! I need to place a style on this element, either inline or through `CSS`, that will place my link *all* the way at the bottom no matter what. Any ideas?

Comment: Did it work? I've read that many email clients don't allow position: absolute. I'm looking for a way to do this as my unsubscription div also stays at the middle of the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure its before `</body>` tag.
Why not to do string replace?

```
$html = str_replace([yourDIVcode] . '</body>', '</body>', $html);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, problem is my emails do not have `<html>` or `<body>` tags. It is really just a `<div>` containing other `<div>`'s

Comment: Well, first, it better to do proper HTML formatting.... Second, If that's the case - then your initial code should work fine, Any email client will wrap your HTML into <body>, and in that case, the unsubscribe link will be last one. Just make sure that all your <div>s are properly closed

Comment: I needed to do a few things differently, but ultimately I did end up doing a `str_replace` and I felt like this answer helped guide me towards that line of thinking. Thanks much!